# Поиск топика по названи в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

**Здрасть, возможно есть много воды.** Я начал разрабатывать бота для телеграмма и подумал, почему бы не сделать хранение текстовых данных в группе-фоурме. В телеграм как раз относительно недавно появилась функция фоурма, где телеграм "оdiscordили", так ведь же в теории можно реализовать хранилище данных, отвязанного от какого либо устройства, в случае например падения сервера.

**Цель:**
В моих планах создать бота, который бы умел сохранять анкеты пользователей (допустим через `bot.forward_message`) в топике с названием `message.from_user.id` отправителя. - реализовал, ура!
И также должен уметь данные пользователя (анкеты) отправлять обратно, по требованию пользователя. Как это реализовать, я не смог найти :(

Краткий алгоритм действий:

> *`/get` > бот ищет топик с `message.from_user.id` > кидает в чат с `message.from_user.id`*

*Использую pyTelegramBotAPI или как его ещё называют telebot*

Comment: Правильно я вас понимаю, вы хотите пересылать сообщение в некую группу/канал, а затем нигде не сохраняя  id сообщений иметь доступ к этим самым id, что бы из сообщений выгружать данные?

Comment: Нет, id сохраняется в названии топика или первом сообщении топика

Comment: А почему просто в группу не скидывать сообщения с анкетой? А потом забирать от туда эти сообщения.

Comment: Можно, но всё равно надо как-то найти это сообщение и сортировать их, поскольку пользователь может иметь несколько анкет.

Comment: А в чем проблема сохранять id сообщений или вы не хотите этого делать принципиально?